# How to logout from FB in android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the code which is provided in facebook SDK, and the code is working fine. 
But I want to logout from facebook.

How can I do that?

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.facebook.*;
    import com.facebook.model.*;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getId() + "!");
                    String id=user.getId().toString();
                    String name=user.getName().toString();

                  ;
                  }
                }
              }).executeAsync();
            }
          }
        });
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I havn't worked with this API before but according to facebook you can use

```
session.close()
```

See documentation for [close()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/#close)

```
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation()
```

See documentation for [closeAndClearTokenInformation()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/#closeAndClearTokenInformation).

"Once a Session has been closed, it can't be re-opened; a new Session must be created."